# how do I insert images into a database?

Tags: php, mysql, image

I'm learning mysql and am having tremendous trouble with this code to build an image database....

I know how to create a table and I know I need longblob for images. Not a problem. Currently I'm creating via: `CREATE TABLE pics 
( 
picid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
filename varchar(255) not null unique, 
caption varchar(255) not null, 
pic longblob not null 
);`

the "**not null**" in picid is giving me problems.  Because next when I attempt to populate using this code:
`INSERT INTO pics values 
( 
NULL, 
'bear.jpg', 
'a picture of a bear', 
LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/USERS_NAME/Pictures/bear.jpg') 
);`

I get hit with the error #1048 - Column 'pic' cannot be null.

please help. I am losing my mind....

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:sql-server] ... the answer is you *shouldn't* be storing images in a database.

Comment: the sql-server tag was suggested...I'm learning dude..I've been advised to use paths instead of just loading pics into the database

Answer (score 2):

It's not the `picid` that's the problem. `LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/USERS_NAME/Pictures/bear.jpg')` most likely fails and returns `NULL`.

Not to mention, you shouldn't store images in a database. Images are files, and should be stored as such on the file system. The database should hold the metadata + the file's address in the filesystem.

See [Effeciently storing user uploaded images on the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203031/effeciently-storing-user-uploaded-images-on-the-file-system) for a good system to follow.

Comment: load_file should be returning that file though...the path isn't "empty". It is correct.

Comment: @acegreene2: There's a very large gap between "should" and "is". Make sure LOAD_FILE is returning what you think it does. Also, please read the rest of the answer too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  the article you referred me to is a bit too advanced btree isn't something I have experience with.  But my path uses forward slashes instead of backslashes (b/c backslashes are escape commands in mysql) should I just use double backslashes?

Comment: what code/architecture would you use to build and populate this sort of database?

Answer (score 0):

if you still want to continue using the blob method try this tutorial
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40286-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php/